# Understanding of how to use "Container View" in iOS Designer

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio, uicontainerview

One can add a `Container View` on an existing view with the help of `iOS Designer`. A container view is placed on the existing view with an embed segue to a new added view controller. The new added view controller is responsible for the content of the container view.

One problem is that you can't change the embed segue or create a new embed segue. The only way is described [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19128/container-view-in-xamarin-ios). But how do you use that? I saw an [example](http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers) by exchanging the view controller in the container. That's not what I want. I want to display multiple view controllers in one container, but I only get this managed by code.

So for what use cases is this `Container View` element?

Comment: By "iOS Designer" do you mean "Interface Builder"?

Comment: iOS Designer is nearly the same thing like Interface Builder. Don't know if here the concepts are 100% the same, but perhaps you could explain the Interface Builder way and I check if this is also possible in the iOS Designer.

Comment: OK, will do. Just writing an answer now.

Comment: Can you clear up what you mean by "display multiple view controllers in one container". How do you want it to work? Do you mean you want to switch between them? Or have tabs? Or what?

Comment: In my case I want to have up to three `UITableViewController` side by side.

Comment: Hmm... are you sure you want this? That doesn't seem very user friendly. What is the interaction you are after? i.e. what do the three table views do that requires all three to be on the screen at the same time?

Comment: The user selects a row in table 1, table 2 shows the results. The user selects a row in table 2 and table 3 shows the results. Don't know what's wrong about this. A container should be perfect for this, but I don't know if this is possible in IB/iOS Designer.

Comment: Ah ok, let me update my answer... When you said "next to each other." I though you meant three really skinny tables on the screen at the same time.

Comment: Wait... Are these tables covering the entire screen? Or just part (like half or something) of it with other UI elsewhere on the screen.

Comment: I don't know a similar app. I'll do something like replicating `UISplitViewController` but here only two view controllers are used. I want to have three. All three tables have the same size (a third). Only navigation bar and bottom toolbar is on the screen. The advantage of a "Container View" seems to be that you can add every other view controller in IB/iOS Designer (without using code).

Comment: OK, I can't comment too much as I don't know about your app. What I will point out though is to possibly use a PopoverViewController or something similar. This provides a small, modal area for the user to select something (like showing your tables). And allows you to use a navigation controller to make it easy for the user to navigate the data. Don't try to create your own interaction behaviours. All you will do is confuse the user. Take a look at the UI Elements section of this... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/

Comment: What you are trying to do might seem easier and might seem like it uses less code. You will soon find out that you are wrong. You are also trying to create a brand new, never seen before, interaction for the user. This will just be confusing. Also what happens if (as a user) I have selected something in table 1. And then table 2. And then I change my selection in table 1?

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I already use popover for another type of data. Currently it is a prototype and it depends on how the user will react. My goal is not to use less code. To your question: Because table 2 depends on table 1, table 2 changes if another selection is made in table 1. The content of table 3 will be blank at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Container View" is a bit of a misnomer in this case. It doesn't actually **contain** anything.

What it does is place a `frame` onto the "parent" view controller's view to show you where the **contained** view will appear.

By doing this you can then use constraints on it and design around it etc...

If you want multiple separate view controllers to be contained in a parent view controller then you can always just add additional container views and set them up with new container segues.

But I think there might be a better way to achieve what you want to do.

**Update**

OK, from what it sounds like you want to have Table 1 on the screen. Then the user selects something and then table 2 is shown. Then Table 3. etc...

To do this I would do the following...

Make your "container segue" point to a navigation controller. Not to a table.

Then the root view of your navigation controller will be table 1. Then you can use normal "push" segues to go to table 2 and table 3. You can even put these into the designer and use segues.

So like this...

```
[] = view controller
() = segue

[Parent]-(embed)-[Navigation Controller]-(root)-[Table1]-(push)-[Table2]-(push)-[Table3]
```

That should do what you want.

Comment: Then "Container View" is not the same as [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)? So only one view controller per container? Ok, I never saw it like this but it should work.

Comment: @testing yeah, "container view **controller**" in that link means that the view controller is not actually showing content, it is there to hold views that belong to other view controllers that show content. i.e. NavigationController doesn't actually have any content. TabBarController doesn't have any content. etc... What I would do in your case is use a navigation controller (like I have suggested in the edit) to create the interaction you want.

Comment: Your approach is a good idea. Because I want to use the space on an iPad I'll place three containers side by side as you mentioned as not as ideal solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Fogmeister hi,how i can reuse my viewcontrollers inside Container view!? To not recreate when i'm switching between them?!

Comment: @VetaLio in IB you can drag multiple "Embed" segues to one view controller. Drag a container onto the view and just deleted its associated view controller and connect your one.

Comment: @Fogmeister ty for the reply. I'm doing pretty the same(like this TUT http://www.blogaboutxamarin.com/using-the-containerview-to-transition-between-views-aka-more-fragments-in-xamarin-ios/ ).  How to achieve this "connect",if i always doing "removeFromparentViewController" and "addToParentViewController'!? As i understood correctly that is the API of container view? Any idea how to workaround this?